# How to fix the line size for my SQL query output in the command line?

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sql-query-store

Can anyone please sort out the issue I am having with the output format of my SQL command line below? I tried setting the line size to 200 but it did not work. Would appreciate a quick fix.

[image]

Comment: uncheck "wrap text output on resize" in the cmd window properties, then resize to something huge, and rerun your query

Comment: @allmhuran, It is still showing me the same output format. How do I fix it?

Comment: OK, exit out of sqlcmd (ctrl+c) (or whichever command line tool you are uisng) and type `mode x,y` where `x` is output buffer width in characters, and `y` is buffer height in characters. Choose something stupidly large, like `mode 1000,50`.  Then go back into sqlcmd and run your queries

Comment: @allmhuran where should i type mode 1000,50 if i exit out of sqlcmd?

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were firing up a command prompt and then starting something within that, like sqlcmd (as in, the actual sqlcmd program). Is that not the case?

Comment: @allmhuran i have messaged you with another screenshot. Kindly respond.